# how to perform log out function when app force quits or crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-applications

I want to perform log out function when the app force quits or crashes unexpectedly. To perform this task i need to call a web service to remove my information from server side database.But i am unable to call a web service when app force quits or crashes. So please help me out to resolve this.

> `applicationWillTerminate`

and

> applicationWillResignActive

delegate method did not work for me!

Thanks!

Comment: i doubt there is some delegate (or any app code except some low level error handling) called on force quit or crash due to nature of the termination...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways in which an app can exit where it's going to be difficult (maybe impossible) to intercept and cause code to execute.  You would be better off having the host system detect a disconnect or timeout and log out the user automatically from that side.

Comment: You can't do it reliably from inside your app.  The **web service** should be made to handle the situation when a client goes away abruptly.

Comment: but how we inform this to server from our app some application like ebay has done these thing it seems like

Comment: You don't.  The server should detect that there's a broken connection or timeout.  Example: On Apple's developer forum, if you leave your browser inactive for some time you have to login again...the host software does that with no help from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Two work-arounds might work:

1. Incorporate a timeout function.  If the user doesn't process information or trigger active code to register within a certain time frame, automate a request to the web service to remove his/her/your information.
2. Have a small recurring code run constantly in the background of your app.  Make it as minimal as you can to reduce memory footprint.  Make the code send a bit or byte of information every so often to your server.  The server could automatically delete it if you'd like.  Should this "signal" cease, automate a request to the web service to remove his/her/your information.

Answer (score 1):

By "force quitting" I assume you mean that the system kills the app. In this case the `applicationWillTerminate` method will be called. From the Apple docs:

> ...this method may be called in situations where the application
>   is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to
>   terminate it for some reason

I assume the same happens when the user kills the app from the task switcher (you'd need to test).

If the app crashes then by the very nature of the failure, none of the appDelegate methods are called.

Comment: my question was how we can call the web service in such situation